# PHP multiple timer function instances

Tags: php, html, function, loops, timer

I'm making a site where users post text posts and each post has a countdown timer on, different for each one. I am having a problem where I am only able to have one timer running.

I have a function to get the time depending on the time in the database for the post and the current time. The php file loops through each post and calls the time function to get the time for each post. However it is only creating one timer.

code for the timer

```
function getTime($conn, $pid){
        $countDownDate;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM userposts";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if ($row['pid'] == $pid){ // getting the row of the user
                $countDownDate = $row['time'];
            }
        }
        echo "<p style='color:black' id='demo'></p>
            <script>

            // Set the date we're counting down to
            var countDownDate = new Date('".$countDownDate."');

            // Update the count down every 1 second
            var x = setInterval(function() {

              // Get todays date and time
              var now = new Date().getTime();

              // Find the distance between now an the count down date
              var distance = countDownDate - now;

              // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
              var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
              var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
              var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
              var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

              // Display the result in the element with id='demo'
              document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = days + 'd ' + hours + 'h '
              + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's ';

              // If the count down is finished, write some text
              if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById('demo').style.color = 'red';
                document.getElementById('demo').style.fontWeight = '900';
                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
              }
            }, 1000);
            </script></br>";
    }
```

code to get time in each post

```
function getPosts(){

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<div class='post-box'><p>";

        // displaying time
        getTime($conn,$row['pid']);

        echo "</p></div>";
    }
}
```

it is only displaying the time for the first post in the loop

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
class="demo"
```

instead of

```
id="demo"
```

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).
>   Check
>   [How to use HTML id Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the getTime function with this one because I think you are getting only one record from that table:

```
function getTime($conn, $pid){
    $countDownDate;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userposts WHERE pid = '" . $pid . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $countDownDate = $row['time'];

    echo '<p style="color: black;" class="counter" data-countdowndate="' . $countDownDate . '"></p><br />';
}
```

Then, the Javascript code would be writen only once for all counters, here is a working example:

```js
var counters = document.getElementsByClassName('counter');
var intervals = new Array();

for (var i = 0, lng = counters.length; i < lng; i++) {
  (function(i) {
   var x = i;
    
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    intervals[i] = setInterval(function() {
      var counterElement = counters[x];
      var counterDate = counterElement.dataset.countdowndate;

      // Set the date we're counting down to
      var countDownDate = new Date(counterDate);

      // Get current date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Display the result in the element with id='demo'
      counterElement.innerHTML = days + 'd ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's';

      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(intervals[x]);
        counterElement.style.color = 'red';
        counterElement.style.fontWeight = '900';
        counterElement.innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
      }
    }, 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<span style="color:black" class="counter" data-countdowndate="2018-12-06 01:08:28"></span><br />
<span style="color:black" class="counter" data-countdowndate="2018-12-12 11:07:29"></span><br />
<span style="color:black" class="counter" data-countdowndate="2018-12-13 12:06:30"></span><br />
<span style="color:black" class="counter" data-countdowndate="2018-12-14 13:05:31"></span><br />
<span style="color:black" class="counter" data-countdowndate="2018-12-15 14:04:32"></span><br />
```